# Is there any way to count identifiers of Stored Procedures?

Tags: rdbms

Is there any way to count identifiers of SQL Stored Procedures and/or functions?

This identifiers can be: SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, IF, While or other SQL Expression.

An identifier is the minimum unit of separation of the SQL interpreter and from what I understand there is no “public” way to count it...

Comment: Those aren't identifiers.  Those are SQL keywords.  Your question is really unclear.

Comment: In SQL, identifiers are object names. E.g. table or column names.

Comment: Do you mean "statements"?  Any answer depends in part on the dialect of SQL — which DBMS are you interested in?  The answer to "how many statements are there in a given stored procedure" is not one for which there is a standard answer.  Indeed, most DBMS won't provide the answer easily — it isn't an important statistic to the DBMS.  So it is likely you'll end up with code to parse the dialect(s) of SQL you work with.

Comment: Note, too, that a single SELECT statement might have multiple CTEs (common table expressions, aka WITH clauses), each of which contains one or more SELECT statements, and the main SELECT body might well contain multiple occurrences of SELECT; it probably isn't as simple as counting the keywords.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)